# bootstrap nav items and flex items centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic bootstrap navigation with navbar logo and brand name. Also 2 items with "Home" and "Others". And below navigation, I have 2 divs in flex. Here is my simple code in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/canerucal/pen/dyZreep).

My problems are:

- Navbar-items (home and others) going right and not centered on main nav class. I tried bootstrap's "justify-content-center" but items are centered on child div.
- "hello-user" div should be centered on user-wrapper div. But it centered on hello-user div right now.
- "today-field" div should be on right. I achieve that goal.

Here is result:
[image: result]

Here is what I need:
[image: achieve]

Here is my CSS. You can check all code from [CodePen](https://codepen.io/canerucal/pen/dyZreep).

```
body {
  font-family: "Merriweather", sans-serif;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #8a68ff;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  color: #ffffffc0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.hello-userID .today-field {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.bold-userID {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.user-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.hello-user {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.today-field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.hello-userID {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add to the .navbar-nav this properties

```
.navbar-nav {
    margin-right: 166px !important;
}
```

On the other hand you can give a class to the image which one under the `job-logo` div class, like this:

```
<img src="https://image.pngaaa.com/96/2278096-middle.png" width= 70, height= 77 alt="user-job-logo" class="tooth" />
```

And add this properties to the tooth class

```
.tooth {
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

finally looks like this:

[image: Tooth]

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry for question I am newbie: Is this "margin-left" effects the responsive design?

Comment: Yes effects but you should redesign the classes with media queries. I tried to give me-5 to the navbar-nav class but  It couldn't be enough for putting middle them.

Comment: What should I do if I want to responsive design in future?

Comment: You should specify each class for each breakpoint value with media queries. Maybe there is another practical solution but that's all I can do.